# Something wrong with json response

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I new at programming i want to show recycler view,nothing error in code sheet but at log i found  `com.example.beaconsenjacoffee.ListPromo$1.onResponse(ListPromo.java:49)`
 whats wrong with my code?

```
public class ListPromo extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<NotificationList> data;
private DataAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_promo);
    initviews();
}
private void initviews(){
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    loadJSON();

}
private void loadJSON(){
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://api.learn2crack.com")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface request = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            data = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getListNotif()));
            adapter = new DataAdapter(data);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error",t.getMessage());

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: post your logcat values

Comment: show your JSONResponse class and apiInterface class

Comment: Also show your Json response. Have you added correct URL in your above code? As i checked your url, it has only "Hello" string in response.

Comment: i also checked it is only returning the "Hello"

Comment: public class JSONResponse {
    public NotificationList[] ListNotif;

    public NotificationList[] getListNotif(){
        return ListNotif;
    }


}

Comment: public interface RequestInterface {
    @GET("android/jsonandroid")
    Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}

Comment: https://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonandroid/

Comment: the end point is android/jsonandroid

Comment: at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3826)
        at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3813)
        at com.example.beaconsenjacoffee.ListPromo$1.onResponse(ListPromo.java:49)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:66)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)

Comment: @BedjoLucky add the logcat messages to your question by editing it! And format it as code to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

**Incorrect URL**

`URL ="http://api.learn2crack.com"`

Check the url you are passing returning invalid `json` Value ie `"Hello"`

Example:-
Valid `URL = "https://api.androidhive.info/contacts/"`

https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonandroid

the end point android/jsonandroid